# Get text in td without button

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to get the content in the "some content" `<td>`. I don't want the content of the button.

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
   var content = $(this).closest('td').not('button').text();
   console.log();
});


<tr>
   <td>hello</td>
   <td>some content <button type="button" class="edit">Edit</button></td>
</tr>
```

Right now it's showing:

some content [huge space right here] Edit

Result I want:

some content [no space whatsoever]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this to get text.

```
var content = $(this).closest('td').text().replace($(this).text(), '').trim();
```

But it's bad idea. Because if you'll have code like this

`<td>Editsome content <button type="button" class="edit">Edit</button></td>`

As result you'll have 'some contentEdit'
So it's better to put 'some text' for example to `<span class="content">` and get it by class selector.

`<td><span class="content">some content </span><button type="button" class="edit">Edit</button></td>`

`$(this).closest('td').children('.content').text()`

or put you `button` to another `td`